# Changing resource in the runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, dynamicresource

Let's suppose, that we've got the following dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="Test">Ala ma kota</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This dictionary is merged somewhere in custom control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I completely change value of the resource "Test" during application runtime from the code behind?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I want to do it from the codebehind. I know, that I can manually create binding, but I suspect, there's another, simpler way :)

Comment: If you asking to change that string from code behind then take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can change `resource from code-behind` but main thing is how you are binding to that resource i.e. via `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`.

Modify like this -

```
Resources["Test"] = "Ala ma kota updated";
```

**XAML** (After resource update from code behind, text value will differ for two approaches) -

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Test}"/>  // Will be Ala ma kota
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Test}"/> // Will be Ala ma kota updated
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change a resource from code behind then just access the resource like a dictionary and change desired value :)

Like this:

```
this.Resource["myThickness"] = new Thickness(2);
```

That would be it :)